# I can't show data in dom after api id matched by conditional

Tags: reactjs, api

I can't set conditionally

```
const [food, setFood] = useContext(UserContext)
```

- when I click a product I get a id from food

```
let { img, name, description, price,id } = item;
```

- it's my API items

```
     food === item.id ?{img, name}: console.log('undifind');
    console.log(name);
```

- problems are here
- I wanna show `a specific item` after `2 id` matching

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from '../../App';

export default function CartInfo({item}) {
    const [food, setFood] = useContext(UserContext)

    let { img, name, description, price,id } = item;

     food === item.id ?{img, name}: console.log('undifind');
    console.log(name);
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: you mean that every 2 id matches you want to render a certian component?
Clarify Please

Comment: when the user clicks a product that id comes in Cart components.
if id matches with API id user see that product in detail.
then that product shows in dom

Comment: You can consider to do this check at API level instead of view one

Comment: I can match id but I can't show dom

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this solution?

```
import React, { useContext,useState } from 'react'
import { UserContext } from '../../App';

export default function CartInfo({item}) {
    const [food, setFood] = useContext(UserContext)
    const [showProduct, setShowProduct] = useState(false)
    
    useEffect(() => {
        let { img, name, description, price,id } = item;
        if(food === item.id) {
            setShowProduct(true)
        }
    }, [item]);

    return (
        showProduct ? <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-4"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
            <div className="col-md-2"></div>
        </div> : null
    )
}
```